# Computing the expected value of a random variable depending on another one:

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$Y$ is a standard normal random variable and $X$ is a random variable described by the following:

$$
    X = 
\begin{cases}
    Y,& \text{if } Y\gt\alpha\\
    0,& \text{if } Y\leqslant \alpha
\end{cases}
$$
Compute $E[X]$.

Should I use the cdf? But how do I do it?

I thought about doing:

$$E[X] = E[Y]\times Pr(Y\gt\alpha) + 0\ \times Pr(Y\leqslant \alpha) = E[Y](1 - \Phi(\alpha)) = 0$$ But when I give it a second thought it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I actually disagree @BruceET (but I may be wrong), it does not consider the mass at 0, take $\alpha=0.5$ for example, then (here in Julia) `a=randn(100000); sum(a[a.>0.5])/length(a)` will give roughly $0.35$  whereas and `a=randn(100000); mean(a[a.>0.5])` will give roughly $1.14$. I think the first one is the one that is asked by the OP, the second is the truncated gaussian.

Comment: Good point. Comment deleted.

Comment: $$E(X)=E(Y\,\mathbf 1_{Y>\alpha})=\int_\alpha^\infty y\,\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dy=\left.-\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right|_\alpha^\infty=\frac{e^{-\alpha^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your first term $E[Y]P(Y>\alpha)$ is wrong because it assumes that $Y$ and $\mathbf 1_{Y\ge \alpha}$ are independent.

I think the best is to visualize the pdf of $X$ which is constituted of mass at at $0$ and then a truncated gaussian from $\alpha$ onwards. So for the expected value you're left with

$$ \kappa \int_\alpha^\infty y p(y)\mathrm{d}y $$

where $p(y)$ is the pdf of $Y$ and $\kappa$ is the appropriate normalization constant (it should be easy to see that it is equal to $1-\Phi(\alpha)$).

The integral is the expected value of a half-gaussian: which is equal to

$$ {p(\alpha)\over 1-\Phi(\alpha)} $$

so that finally,

$$ \mathbb E[X] = p(\alpha) $$

which you can easily check numerically (here in Julia)

```
N = int(1e6)
alpha = 0.7

Y = randn(N)

mask = (Y.>alpha)

X = map(y->(y>alpha)?y:0, Y)

cdf(x) = 0.5*(1+erf(x/sqrt(2)))
pdf(x) = exp(-x^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi))

# check the mean of a half gaussian
mean(Y[Y.>alpha])-pdf(alpha)/(1-cdf(alpha))

# compare the mean of X and the theoretical mean
mean(X)
pdf(alpha)
```

the last two values should be pretty close (I got less than 0.1% difference when trying).

Comment: The conditioning/deconditioning is not necessary.

Comment: saw your comment on the OP question, neat and brief!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the half Gaussian, so I'll get into that in a couple of hours. But what is the mass at 0? You said "mass at at 0".

Comment: Well X can be 0 with nonzero probability so there is "probability mass" at zero, for example X can't be below $min(\alpha,0) so there is no probability mass below that . It's a way to refer to the support of the pdf of X